# Get page by template?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pages, templates, sub-menu

I'm in a complicated situation. I'll try to explain it as easy as possible.

Imagine the following pages:

- Page 1
- Page 2

  - Subpage 1
  - Subpage 2
  - Subpage 3

Each subpage of page 2 lists posts from a custom post type with a specific taxonomy. Let's call the post type Objects, and the taxonomy just Categories, to keep it simple.

To list the different posts from the different Categories, i have three different page templates for the subpages: `subpage-1-templ.php`, `subpage-2-templ.php` and `subpage-3-templ.php`. Each one of these templates lists the posts from a specific Category for the post type (Objects). It's hardcoded.

So far all good, it works as expected. It's a little ugly to have to hardcode it but i don't know of any other way, so this'll have to work for now. (I'd prefer to ditch wordpress alltogether but that's another story)

All of those subpages lists the siblings in a sub menu. So, if you're on subpage 2 it will show subpage1, 2 and 3 (but subpage 2 has a current class on it). Works good.

Now to the actual problem; when you click one of the posts listed in a subpage, you get to a page which displays more info for the post, as expected. The problem is i want to show the submenu for page 2 in there (so, subpage1, 2 and 3). I don't know how to do that without hardcoding it.

Perhaps, and i don't know if this will work, but maybe i can find a page by it's template. I can create a template for page 2 (not for it's children, the actual parent page) called `objects-template.php` and then on a post, i can grab the page that uses the template, then get all it's children, and then just simply list them up. I just don't know how to get a page by it's template, if that's even possible (Preferably by the template file name, but the template name works too).

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

```
    // Query looks fine right?
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'objects-parent-page-template.php'
    ));
    // Dump the id (also tried just getting the object with get_queried_object(), still get null)
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($query->get_queried_object_id()); die();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page template's filename is stored as a post meta with key '_wp_page_template', so basically you can use `get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);` to get the template filename for the page with ID `$post_id`.

You can also do the reverse (i.e. getting id from page template filename) using [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in `WP_Query` or other wordpress functions.

Also there is a conditional function [is_page_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) which checks if the current page's template is the one specified in parameter

These will probably solve your problem & maybe help to get rid of the hardcoded stuff.

Comment: Awesome, i'll take a look at it!

Comment: I tried using WP_Query to get the id of the page with the template, but it returns null for some reason. If i do a custom query against the database selecting the key and value it is found, but WP_Query returns null. Please see edited OP for code snippet. Any ideas?

Comment: did you set 'post_type' to 'page'? The default value is only 'post'

Comment: I'm guessing you only add another item in the array? `'post_type' => 'page'` <- that didn't work. No error messages, just still null.

Comment: this has to be something with parameters. Is the page published? Does the filename matches that in the database? Is the filename showing when you use `get_post_meta` with that page's id?

Comment: It's really weird. The page is indeed published, the filename is identical to what is stored in the database, and i do get the filename when using get_post_meta() with the page id. Am i getting the results correctly (by using $query->get_queried_object()) or is there another way to get the query result? That might be what's causing it?

Comment: `$query->get_posts()` or `$query->query($args)` maybe?

Comment: Yup, it was that easy; get_posts() worked! Thanks a bunch!